# Powershell move all files and subfolders in a child folder to CURRENT directory

Tags: powershell

I tried this, no error but no files have modved :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "subfolder\" -Recurse |  Move-Item -Destination "."
```

Update: *I don't want ABSOLUTE but RELATIVE path*

Comment: You could try something like `gci '.\subfolder\' -Recurse -File |%{Move-Item -Path ($_.FullName)}`, but what if you have stuff with the same name? 
You'll need to provide some error handling in it?
If eg. you have two files with the name 'file.txt', you'd be overwriting them with the -Force flag.
It would be solved by saving the gci-object into an array and then checking for entries with the same name... ?

Comment: I love PowerShell, but this sounds like a job for RoboCopy. No?

Comment: @Steven no I have just a few files but a lot of times and I want to put it in profile and be called by some other powershell functions. Also potentially want to port to powershell Linux.

Comment: @ITM thanks it works except for hidden .git file will search how to cope with hidden files now ;)

Comment: @AdminOfThings -Recurse doesn't preserve hierarchy ? I thought I need it to copy all folders and subfolders.

Comment: @user310291: gci -Force will show you the hidden files.

Comment: Also with '`Move-Item -Path 'subfolder\*' -Destination . -Force`  you might end up as you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer will be something like:

```
Move-Item -Path 'subfolder\*' -Destination . -Force
```

This is relative and will process all hidden files and folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-Location 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\newFolder';
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\oldFolder\*.txt' -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $(get-location).Path;
```

Comment: I don't want ABSOLUTE but RELATIVE path ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a crazy attempt and to be honest the question isn't as comprehensive as I'd like.  For example: I'm not sure if the folder will only every be 1 level deep or could be further down from the current directory.  At any rate, I got something that seems to be working basically by not bothering with recursion:

```
$SubFolder = 'YourFolderName'
$SubFolder = Get-Item .\$SubFolder

Get-ChildItem $SubFolder |
ForEach-Object{
    $Destination = $_.FullName -Replace "$($SubFolder.FullName.Replace('\','\\'))", ".\"
    $NewParent   = $Destination -Replace $_.Name 

    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $NewParent    
}
```

I think the trick here is you have to move to the parent's parent, etc or however many levels back/up.  So figure out what the new parent should be using the current directory syntax `.\`.  Once you have that you can move everything from the first level over not using recursion.  `Move-Item` on a folder it knows to move the whole thing, and the files that are found in Sub-folder itself will obviously move to the new correct parent.

I had another working version that did use recursion, but this seems more concise and much to my surprise this seems to work.  However, I'm not thrilled with it.